# Describe the set $\Bbb{A}_{\Bbb{Q}}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

There is an exercise (exercise 3.2C) in Vakil's algebraic geometry book needs to describe the set of all prime ideal of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$.

What I have done, first $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ is PID therefore all the prime ideal correspond to some irreducible polynomials or zero, however I am not sure if this exercise asked more for example the geometric picture of it, for the $\Bbb{R}[x]$ the irreducible polynomial can have at most degree 2, and those polynomial of degree 2 correspond to the points that glue the conjugate points together. Is there more structure of $\Bbb{Q}[x]$ (than simply the irreducible polynomials)?

Comment: This is clearly not the same question. Someone even marked it as duplicate. Whoever this was: please read again.

Comment: Topic: Don't forget the zero ideal.

Comment: Oh yes, I forget the generic point [(0)]

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg a question does not have to be the same question to be marked as a duplicate - rather, the criteria is that the answer to the duplicate target should answer this question as well. The following sentence in the accepted answer at the link would seem to do it, no?

> Geometrically, you can think of the point $(f(x))$ as describing the set of all of its roots, as an orbit of the action of the Galois group $G = \text{Gal}(\bar{k}/k)$ on the points of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ over $\bar{k}$.

Comment: In fact @KReiser I was wondering if there is something special to $\Bbb{Q}$ other than simply treated it as arbitary $k$? (I know nothing about it I just wondering)